# No sound MSI B85M-G43 Haswell

Tags: sound, lubuntu

So far I haven’t been able to get sound to work.  Here are the diagnostics I’ve done and notes I’ve made:
The motherboard is an MSI B85M-G43.  Any tips to lead me in the right direction would be appreciated.  I believe I've got a good load of information here.

---

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 041e (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B85 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

---

I installed **xfce4-mixer**, and it sees HDA Intel MID and HDA Intel PCH.  I set it to PCH after I saw that MID is most likely just the SPDIF jack.

I found that by RightClick System Tray (just left of clock) > Panel Settings > Panel Applets tab > Double Click Volume Control
It gave me a DOS style window sound config AlsaMixer.  When the Card says MID you only have SPDIF outputs, when the Card is changed to PCH you have Surround, Center, Side, Line, etc.
The PCH chip says Realtek ALC892.
The MID chip says Intel Haswell HDMI.

NOTE: lspci shows a Realtek NIC, but not Audio.

**cat /proc/asound/cards**

```
 0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                      HDA Intel MID at 0xf7d14000 irq 46
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d10000 irq 45
```

---

Gnome MPlayer will appear to "play" audio just fine, but no sound comes out.  Trying to play video gave an error and choked* the system.
VLC gives an error for either and chokes* the system playing video.  The error is
      Audio output failed:
      The audio device "default" could not be used:
      No such file or directory.

* choke means that the system performed agonizingly slow, and trying to kill the offending task was a painful exercise in patience.

**aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

**arecord -l**

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC892 Alt Analog [ALC892 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

## snippet from **dmesg**

```
...
[    8.897758] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    8.897807] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.897921] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.898023] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    8.911128] SKU: Nid=0x1d sku_cfg=0x4027f603
[    8.911130] SKU: port_connectivity=0x1
[    8.911131] SKU: enable_pcbeep=0x0
[    8.911132] SKU: check_sum=0x00000007
[    8.911133] SKU: customization=0x000000f6
[    8.911133] SKU: external_amp=0x0
[    8.911134] SKU: platform_type=0x0
[    8.911134] SKU: swap=0x1
[    8.911135] SKU: override=0x1
[    8.911537] autoconfig: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[    8.911539]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.911541]    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.911542]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.911543]    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    8.911544]    inputs:
[    8.911546]      Front Mic=0x19
[    8.911548]      Rear Mic=0x18
[    8.911549]      Line=0x1a
[    8.911551] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x4027f603 for NID 0x1d
[    8.911552] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0xf603 CODEC_ID=10ec0892
[    8.923063] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input5
[    8.923744] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input6
[    8.923980] HDA driver get symbol successfully from i915 module
[    8.924017] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    8.924249] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input7
[    8.924402] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input8
[    8.924468] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input9
[    8.924524] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input10
[    8.924580] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input11
[    8.924649] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input12
[    8.935434] hda_codec: invalid CONNECT_LIST verb 5[1]:0
[    8.935491] hda_codec: invalid CONNECT_LIST verb 6[1]:0
[    8.935554] hda_codec: invalid CONNECT_LIST verb 7[1]:0
[    8.935855] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input13
[    8.935924] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[    8.935977] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[    9.181090] init: Failed to obtain startpar-bridge instance: Unknown parameter: INSTANCE
[    9.819528] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
...
[49407.631452] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[49407.631537] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[49407.631575] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: setting latency timer to 64
[49407.631602] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[49407.631700] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[49407.631777] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[49407.632532] i8042 kbd 00:09: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[49407.632535] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[49407.632552] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[49407.632576] r8169 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[49407.827509] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[49407.827530] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 4999 at /build/buildd/linux-3.11.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_ddi.c:383 intel_ddi_put_crtc_pll+0x272/0x280 [i915]()
[49407.827551] Modules linked in: zram(C) parport_pc(F) ppdev(F) bnep rfcomm bluetooth nfsd(F) auth_rpcgss(F) nfs_acl(F) nfs(F) lockd(F) sunrpc(F) fscache(F) nls_iso8859_1(F) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek x86_pkg_temp_thermal kvm_intel(F) kvm(F) crct10dif_pclmul(F) crc32_pclmul(F) ghash_clmulni_intel(F) aesni_intel(F) aes_x86_64(F) lrw(F) gf128mul(F) glue_helper(F) ablk_helper(F) cryptd(F) mxm_wmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep(F) snd_pcm(F) snd_page_alloc(F) snd_seq_midi(F) snd_seq_midi_event(F) microcode(F) snd_rawmidi(F) snd_seq(F) snd_seq_device(F) snd_timer(F) i915 serio_raw(F) snd(F) drm_kms_helper mei_me lpc_ich drm mei i2c_algo_bit soundcore(F) coretemp lp(F) parport(F) mac_hid wmi video(F) intel_smartconnect hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 ahci(F) libahci(F) mii(F)
[49407.827553] CPU: 3 PID: 4999 Comm: kworker/u8:21 Tainted: GF        C   3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu
[49407.827553] Hardware name: MSI MS-7823/B85M-G43 (MS-7823), BIOS V3.4 09/18/2013
…
```

--
**dmesg | grep codec**

```
[    8.935434] hda_codec: invalid CONNECT_LIST verb 5[1]:0
[    8.935491] hda_codec: invalid CONNECT_LIST verb 6[1]:0
[    8.935554] hda_codec: invalid CONNECT_LIST verb 7[1]:0
[49407.827551] Modules linked in: zram(C) parport_pc(F) ppdev(F) bnep rfcomm bluetooth nfsd(F) auth_rpcgss(F) nfs_acl(F) nfs(F) lockd(F) sunrpc(F) fscache(F) nls_iso8859_1(F) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek x86_pkg_temp_thermal kvm_intel(F) kvm(F) crct10dif_pclmul(F) crc32_pclmul(F) ghash_clmulni_intel(F) aesni_intel(F) aes_x86_64(F) lrw(F) gf128mul(F) glue_helper(F) ablk_helper(F) cryptd(F) mxm_wmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep(F) snd_pcm(F) snd_page_alloc(F) snd_seq_midi(F) snd_seq_midi_event(F) microcode(F) snd_rawmidi(F) snd_seq(F) snd_seq_device(F) snd_timer(F) i915 serio_raw(F) snd(F) drm_kms_helper mei_me lpc_ich drm mei i2c_algo_bit soundcore(F) coretemp lp(F) parport(F) mac_hid wmi video(F) intel_smartconnect hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 ahci(F) libahci(F) mii(F)
```

---

**cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

---

I decided to try **pavucontrol**, so I installed that.
When I run it I get an error window with `Connection to pulseaudio failed…` It also says it will retry in 5 seconds.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh
```

The output is at [*here*](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5f623499b2cd33e525774506e4fb0da4c1468995).

Answer (score 1):

Going back to give it another shot I decided to install **pulseaudio** then check **pavucontrol**.  It showed controls.  VLC also had no error message and played sound.  So I'm not sure why it didn't work with just alsa, but installing pulse fixed my issue.

I hope this helps someone else.